# Nuget pack for assemblies that are append with version

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec, nuget-spec

I have to tag every .dll with it's version from assembly, 
so from Service.dll it becomes: Service-v1.0.0.21455.dll

I tried this two approaches, but each has flows:

1. Build > Rename > Pack with `nuget pack Service.csproj`
   The challenge is that after I do so, Nuget can't find missing `Service.dll`
   Of course, because it's bin/Release/Service-v1.0.0.21455.dll
2. Build > Rename > Pack with `nuget pack .nuspec`
   Issue I'm facing here is that `dependencies` are missing withing the nuget package

This is brief explanation, let me know if it's 'even possible'/'make sense'/'you need more details'

Comment: the package is versioned. Why would you need to put the version in the assembly's filename. That's the part that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It is the requirement